# jQuery Ajax security for auto suggest script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on some auto-suggest feature.

The script is fairly itself. 
When a character is typed in to the textbox it sends a ajax post (or get) request to the php file which queries the database and returns a result set.

But the problem is that the php file is accessible on its own. So it can be called directly. Is there a way to prevent this and make that php file to serve only the ajax request on my application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be validating everything that comes from the client before it hits the database anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. If your script can be requested, it can be requested by anything. It is possible to differentiate ajax requests from normal ones by testing for the `x-requested-with` header and responding accordingly, that is, if it does not contain the value `XMLHTTPRequest` you simply `exit()` the script. However, headers can always be spoofed. So no, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Anyone can look at your .php and stuff..
The best you can do is protect yourself from SQL injection, and thats about it.
There is no foolproof way to do what you want to do.

**By the way, if someone is actually actively polling your .php nonstop in his/her application, you could probably contact that person's host to terminate his/her account.  Just saying.  **